# SSL On laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

I just created a website with laravel, deployed it on my Virtual Machine, and it's ready to go. Now I need to install an SSl certificate to make the HTTPS version usable.

I asked my boss to buy the SSL Certificate, so how would I use it to make my website's communication encrypted ? Do I install using my Laravel configuration ? or do I install it on apache and it will work for all websites that run through my server ?

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure it in your web server (apache nginx)

Basically what you have to do is:
- Configure certificate
- Configure private key

Apache guide
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Nginx guide
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Certificates are valid for the specified domain. This can be a wildcard like *.example.com or a specific one www.example.com or multiple specific ones.